# No consigo sincronizar mi proyecto ansible /awx

Tags: ansible

Intento sincronizar el proyecto y siempre me da error en las collections por lo que me ha dejado de funcionar  los jobs que me iban.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]